# How can i change datetime format to DD-MM-YYYY in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change format of my datetime 2015-05-28 10:18:32 to 28 May 2015. I'm trying this query but failed.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),column_name,6) AS ndate FROM `table_name` WHERE col_id = 1
```

Comment: What is _algorithm_ about this? (Or PHP, for that matter?)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) as

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%d %b %Y') AS ndate FROM `table_name` WHERE col_id = 1
```

and using `convert` function it should be `106` and not `6`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),column_name,106) AS ndate FROM `table_name` WHERE col_id = 1
```

as

```
6 = dd mon yy //28 May 15
106 = dd mon yyyy //28 May 2015
```

Comment: date_format(column_name, '%d-%m-%Y') - for the format he is asking for

Comment: Just changed the date_format parameters to match the format in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

`106` id the code of getting `28 May 2015`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,column_name,106) AS ndate FROM `table_name` WHERE col_id = 1
```

Check  [SQL Server CONVERT() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)